# Null data retrieved when using Listener for Single Value in Firebase and Geofire

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

My data is currently structured as:

```
Users • 
      userId -
           eyeColour: Blue



userId •
    - geoLocation stuff
```

I'm trying to load data associated with the geolocation node. So say if user A sets location and user B is near user A's set location, he/she can see the attributes of user A (eyeColour). so onKeyEntered(), I'm trying to load the user's information.

Every user has their own unique id. When a user sets a location, the child name will be their unique id. (geofire.setLocation(myUniqueId, myLocation);)

So what I've tried before was using the addListenerForSingleValueEvent since I only need to load the information once.

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                    new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // Get user value
                            String test = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                            // ...
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

I thought this would load the profile/information of the user. But instead, the String 'test' returns null. What am I doing wrong? Should I change my listener?

Comment: You don't store users a strings it seems. Are you looking for something like this: `String test = dataSnapshot.child("eyeColour").getValue(String.class)`?

Comment: I am but I figured out the problem. With your line of code, I was able to retrieve the data. But I also had to fix my code at the top, I have it as "users" when it should have been "Users". Thank you very much :)